# Find the general solution of $4y′′+ 3y′−y=e^{−x}+x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Given $$4y′′+ 3y′−y = e^{−x} + x$$
>
> Find the general solution

I identified this as a non-homogeneous linear equation
so I assumed that my solution,

$$ y = y_h  + y_p$$
$$ 4\lambda^2 + 3\lambda - 1 = 0$$
$$ \lambda = -1 \quad\text{and}\quad \lambda =1/4$$
$$ y_h  = Ae^{x/4} + Be^{-x}$$

However, I am not too sure what should I do to find $y_p$

I do know that my $G(x) = e^{-x} + x$ but am not too sure how to find $y_p$.

Comment: Because the ODE is linear, when your right-hand function $G(x)$ is the sum of two functions ($f_1(x)+f_2(x)$), your guess for $y_p$ should be a guess for the $f_1(x)$ part plus a guess for the $f_2(x)$ part (this is known as the "superposition principle"). So make a guess for $e^{-x}$ and one for $x$ (each guess will as usual involve some constants to be determined), and then add these up to get the form for $y_p$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I do know that my $G(x) = \color{blue}{e^{-x}} + \color{purple}{x}$ but am not too sure how to find $y_p$

Based on the form of $G(x)$ and by linearity you would propose a particular solution of the form:
$$y_p=\color{blue}{Ae^{-x}} + \color{purple}{Bx+C}$$
but because $\color{blue}{Ae^{-x}}$ is already contained in the homogeneous solution ($ y_h  = Ae^{0.25x} + \color{red}{Be^{-x}}$), you multiply with an extra factor $x$:
$$y_p=\color{blue}{A}\color{red}{x}\color{blue}{e^{-x}} + \color{purple}{Bx+C}$$
Now substitute into the differential equation to obtain a linear system in the unknowns ("[undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients)") $A$, $B$ and $C$.

Answer (score 1):

By using the [method of undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients#Typical_forms_of_the_particular_integral) it follows that
$y_p$ has the form
$$y_p(x)=xAe^{-x}+Bx+C$$
where $A,B,C$ are real constants to be determined by plugging $y_p$ into the ODE.

Note that factor $x^1$ which multiplies $Ae^{-x}$ is due to the fact that $\lambda=-1$ has multiplicity $1$ in the characteristic equation (see the final remark [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients#Typical_forms_of_the_particular_integral)).

Comment: I just gave you a $+1$ because you love my sense of humor :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's try
$$y_p = Axe^{-x} + Bx + C $$ 
instead. So
$$y_p' = -Axe^{-x} + Ae^{-x} + B$$
$$y_p'' = Axe^{-x} -2Ae^{-x} $$
So
$$4y′′+ 3y′−y = 4Axe^{-x} -8Ae^{-x} -3Axe^{-x} +3 Ae^{-x}  -Axe^{-x} +3B - Bx - C $$
which is equivalent to 
$$4y′′+ 3y′−y= \underbrace{-5A}_{1}e^{-x}\underbrace{-B}_1x + \underbrace{(3B-C)}_0 = e^{-x} + x$$
By identification, we get
\begin{align}
A &= -\frac{1}{5} \\
B &= -1 \\
C &= -3 
\end{align}
are the corresponding values.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
4y^{\prime\prime} + 3y^{\prime} - y & = e^{-x} + x \Longleftrightarrow 4(y^{\prime\prime} + y^{\prime}) - (y^{\prime} + y) = e^{-x} + x \Longleftrightarrow\\\\
4(y^{\prime} + y)^{\prime} - (y^{\prime} + y) & = e^{-x} + x \Longleftrightarrow 4w^{\prime} - w = e^{-x} + x\quad\text{where}\quad w = y^{\prime} + y
\end{align*}